# Problem with PHP paths: does not see the directory and files in it

Tags: php

I have forms.

1. On the forms should be adding files to the Files folder. (It works, but there is a problem) when I only add a file, it is not added, this error appears instead:

   Warning:Cannot modify header information -headers already sent by (output started at Q:\home\rat\www\pr5\files.php:1) in Q:\home\rat\www\pr5\files.php on line 10
2. The file of the file in the Files folder (it does not work: constantly writes that the file exists, even if there is no such file)
3. The image of the added files (it works too)
4. Deleting files (it does not work completely, the files are not deleted), this error appears:

   Warning: unlink(files/Удалить) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in Q:\home\rat\www\pr5\files.php on line 61

What is the problem with the paths of me? I can not understand. I did everything on the textbook, but does not work ...

files.php

```
<?
    class Files {
        public $files;

        function __construct() {
            $this->files = scandir("files/");
        }

        function redirect($url) {
            header('Location: '.$url);
        }

        function counter() {
            $filename = "count.txt";
            if(file_exists($filename)) {
                $h = fopen($filename, "r+");
                $Content = fread($h, filesize($filename));
                fclose($h);
                $text = $Content + 1;
            } else {
                $text = 1;
            }
            $h = fopen($filename, "w");
            if(fwrite($h, $text)) {
                echo "Вы $text-й посетитель сайта =)";
            } else {
                echo "Что-то не работает на сайте! =(";
                echo "Надо напрячь прогера!";
            }
            fclose($h);
            echo "<hr>";
        }

        function upload() {
            if($_FILES['myfile']) {
                $uploaddir = 'files/';
                $destination = $uploaddir.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
                    $this->redirect('/pr5');
                } else {
                    return "error <br>";
                }
            }
        }

        function search() {
            if($_POST['searchname']) {
                $folder = "files/";
                $file = $searchname;
                $file = $folder.$file;
                if(file_exists($file)) {
                    print "Файл существует";
                } else {
                    print "Файл не существует";
                }
            }
        }

        function delete() {
            if($_POST['delete']) {
                unlink("files/".$_POST['delete']);
                $this->redirect('/pr5');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?
    include "files.php";
    $f = new Files;
    if($_FILES['myfile']) {
        $f->upload();
    }

    if($_POST['delete']) {
        $f->delete();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>pr5</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <?
        $f->counter();
    ?>

    <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "post">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "MAX_FILE_SIZE" value = "30000" />
        <input type = "file" name = "myfile" /><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Отправить" />
    </form>

    <hr>

    <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" method = "post">
        <input type = "text" name = "searchname" /><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Найти" />
    </form>

    <?
        if($_POST['searchname']) {
            $f->search();
        }
    ?>

    <hr>

    <?
        if(count($f->files) > 2) {
    ?>
    <form method = "POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>
            </tr>
            <?
                foreach($f->files as $s) {
            ?>
            <?
                    if($s != '.' and $s != '..') {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <?
                            echo $s;
                        ?> </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type = "submit" name = "delete" value = "<? echo $s; ?>">Удалить</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?
                    }
                    ?>
                <?
                }
                ?>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?
    }
    ?>            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd say you should intensify your search efforts as you are listing common issues already answered elsewhere on SO. Also, noone is going to debug your code, so put more effort and come back once you really hit the wall. Now it is not the case.

Comment: This might help you: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's check this error more closely.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information -headers already sent
```

PHP cannot modify headers - so the point where it realizes something's amiss is when it calls the `header()` function - because

```
output started at Q:\home\rat\www\pr5\files.php:1)
```

So, in that file, at row 1, there is something output. Something that's not PHP.

What *appears* to be line 1 is just

```
<?
```

which should have been perfectly copacetic (well, actually you'd better take the habit of using long tags, so,  "<?php", since that's the established standard).

I am therefore betting something that in that line, unless there is an empty line before it of course, **there is something you cannot see**. My money is on a BOM: three invisible bytes that tell the operating system that file is coded in UTF8 with specific characteristics.

Usually, your editor should have an option to create files *without* a Byte Order Mark.